# How come I can't insert into Mongo? It used to work

Tags: python, django, mongodb, database

```
con = pymongo.Connection(MONGO_DOC_HOST, MONGO_DOC_PORT)
db = con.testdb
datasets = db.datasets

for post in db.datasets.find({"test_set":"xyz"}).sort("num_favs",pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(2):
    print post #this works, and it prints fine!

post = {"hi":"abc"}
mongo_id = datasets.insert(post)
```

When I do `datasets.insert`, and print out the mongo_id.  The id prints!

However, when I do: `db.datasets.find().count()` in the mongo console, the count is still the same...

Weird. When I do this in console..I get this error:

```
> db.datasets.insert({"gooder":"absdlk"})
E11000 duplicate key error index: fabletest.datasets.$flickr_original_1  dup key: { : null }
```

That's weird, I didn't index "gooder" at all.

Comment: When you insert, are you getting back NEW mongoid's? There ***is*** an index automatically created on _id for you, what do the results for **db.datasets.find()** look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you definitely hitting the same database ("testdb") in both cases?
the default db in the shell is "test"